# Highlight PDFs and sort highlights by color

Tags: pdf, highlighting

I am trying to find a solution to a problem in my researching workflow:
When I read through long PDFs I want to highlight different kinds of sections in different colors. E.g. definitions in blue, stuff I want to research further in yellow etc., you get the idea.
Now, which software let's me view only the highlights of a specific color?

My feeling is, this isn't such an exotic wish and not a feature so hard to implement, nonetheless I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

This function exists in [Moon + Reader](http://moondownload.com) for android. But this highlights can't be exported somewhere else and it frustrating me.

Comment: Can you at least add a link?

Comment: http://www.moondownload.com/